# How to query to use sort function for array of dictionary

Tags: couchdb

My data look like below:

```
{
  "name":"blah",
  "address":[{
            "city":"abc"
            }]
},
{
  "name":"blah2",
  "address":[{
            "city":"a"
            }]
}
```

Now I want to have sorted data by city of address. how should I write my index and write selector to select all documents?

UPDATE:
I want to sort first by city and then by name.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with a standard map:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc && doc.address) {
      emit(doc.address[0].city, 1)
  }
}
```

Get docs ordered by key using

```
curl 'https://..../_design/DDOC/_view/VNAME?include_docs=true'
```

EDIT:

If you want to order first by city, and then by name, emit a vector-valued key:

```
function(doc) {
   if (doc && doc.address && doc.name) {
      emit([doc.address[0].city, doc.name], 1)
   }
}
```

Comment: I want so sort by city and then by name.